# {name} is not replaced if they are in the attributes, how to handle?

Tags: xml, scala

The test code is:

```
val s = "#"
val x = <a href="{s}">{s}</a>
println(x)
```

It prints:

```
<a href="{s}">#</a>
```

Notice the `{s}` is still there in the attribute, how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
val s = "#"
val x = <a href={s}>{s}</a>
println(x)
```

Notice no quotes! Prints:

```
<a href="#">#</a>
```

Comment: @Freewind, welcome. what about tagging it as the correct answer? :)

Comment: @edrofurla, sorry for my late